# Inheriting StatefulWidgets causing scaffold context error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create widgets to build views in a way I dont have to type the same code every time. This is what I came up with:

```
/// Common class for all views
class GerenciadorTelaLogada<C extends StatefulWidget> extends State<C> {
  /// View title
  final String titulo;

  // Child widgets
  final Widget child;

  GerenciadorTelaLogada(
      {@required this.titulo, this.child, this.floatingActButton});

  final Widget floatingActButton;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(this.titulo),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),

      // Side Menu
      drawer: GMenu(),

      floatingActionButton: this.floatingActButton,

      // View body
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Color(0xff5b71b3),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: this.child,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then, I created another class that adds some functionality to `GerenciadorTelaLogada` class:

```
// Standard class to all views that as a Form
class GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro<C extends StatefulWidget>
    extends GerenciadorTelaLogada<C> {

  /// Executed when clicked in save button
  final VoidCallback onSalvar;

  /// Construtor
  GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro(
      {@required String titulo, Widget child, @required this.onSalvar})
      : super(titulo: titulo, child: child);

// Adds new widgets
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FloatingActionButton salvarFloatButton = FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.save,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      onPressed: this.onSalvar,
    );

/// Return the base view with additional widgets
    return GerenciadorTelaLogada(
      titulo: this.titulo,
      child: this.child,
      floatingActButton: salvarFloatButton,
    ).build(context);
  }
}
```

Now I can create several views using that class, like so:

```
    class CBandeira extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _CBandeiraState createState() => _CBandeiraState();
    }



class _CBandeiraState extends GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro<CBandeira>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

var formInputs = <GTextBox>[];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro(
      onSalvar: () {
        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
            content: Text("Test"),
          ));
        }
      },
      titulo: "Cadastro de Bandeira",
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  formInputs[index].icon,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                title: formInputs[index],
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SizedBox(height: 10);
            },
            itemCount: formInputs.length),
      ),
    ).build(context);
  }
}
```

Everything works fine except when I try to show a Snackbar, `_CBandeiraState, onSalvar` function return this error:

```
I/flutter (20636): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (20636): The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (20636): Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.
I/flutter (20636): No Scaffold ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to Scaffold.of(). This
I/flutter (20636): usually happens when the context provided is from the same StatefulWidget as that whose build
I/flutter (20636): function actually creates the Scaffold widget being sought.
I/flutter (20636): There are several ways to avoid this problem. The simplest is to use a Builder to get a context that
I/flutter (20636): is "under" the Scaffold. For an example of this, please see the documentation for Scaffold.of():
I/flutter (20636):   https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html
I/flutter (20636): A more efficient solution is to split your build function into several widgets. This introduces a
I/flutter (20636): new context from which you can obtain the Scaffold. In this solution, you would have an outer widget
I/flutter (20636): that creates the Scaffold populated by instances of your new inner widgets, and then in these inner
I/flutter (20636): widgets you would use Scaffold.of().
I/flutter (20636): A less elegant but more expedient solution is assign a GlobalKey to the Scaffold, then use the
I/flutter (20636): key.currentState property to obtain the ScaffoldState rather than using the Scaffold.of() function.
I/flutter (20636): The context used was:
I/flutter (20636):   CBandeira
I/flutter (20636):
I/flutter (20636): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (20636): #0      Scaffold.of (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1456:5)
I/flutter (20636): #1      _CBandeiraState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:gerenciador/views/core/cartao/c_bandeira.dart:43:20)
I/flutter (20636): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:19)
I/flutter (20636): #3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:862:36)
I/flutter (20636): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
I/flutter (20636): #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:504:11)
I/flutter (20636): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:282:5)
I/flutter (20636): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:217:7)
I/flutter (20636): #8      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:475:9)
I/flutter (20636): #9      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
I/flutter (20636): #10     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)
I/flutter (20636): #11     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
I/flutter (20636): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18)
I/flutter (20636): #13     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7)
I/flutter (20636): #14     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
I/flutter (20636): #15     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
I/flutter (20636): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
I/flutter (20636): #17     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
I/flutter (20636): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
I/flutter (20636): #22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:275:10)
I/flutter (20636): #23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:184:5)
I/flutter (20636): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter (20636):
I/flutter (20636): Handler: "onTap"
I/flutter (20636): Recognizer:
I/flutter (20636):   TapGestureRecognizer#033d5
I/flutter (20636): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Am I missing something to accomplish what I am trying to do? I started flutter just a few days ago so I wouldn't be surprised if I am doing this the wrong way.

Comment: first of all this `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());` is deprecated. You should use `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` Second of all you don't pass scaffold context into your class... pass scaffold key and then call it `scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(...)`

Comment: The way you're creating the widgets defeat the purpose of the widget tree, Scaffold.of(context) checks In the widget tree for a scaffold, but you first create CBandeira, then GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro in it's build method who calls GerenciadorTelaLogada. So the widget tree is backwards and there is no scaffold above CBandeira

Comment: @EdwynZN how can I fix the architecture of my code to still being able to create like a fixed template for my views and then use it to create more complex and still being able to use the Snackbar method without context errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're creating CBandeira > GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro > GerenciadorTelaLogada, and instead of letting the StatefulWidget do and call the build method of each one when it's appropiate you're calling them inside the others build method when using `.build(context)`, by doing that you're telling the class to use the context you give them (that's why the error, it cannot find the scaffold up in the tree because you're using the same context), instead of letting the StatefulWidget create its own below in the tree. Take for example GMenu(), it's a widget you create somewhere else and can reuse anytime because of it.

You need to build them from the top widget (the parent class that wraps other) to the bottom, so first you'll need to build the Scaffold, then inside the body you want another class to wrap, and by that logic you go until you get to the tiniest class or widget you need in the tree.

```
//If you're not going to use setState or doens't need to update the widget then just use a StatelessWidget
class GerenciadorTelaLogada extends StatelessWidget {
  final String titulo;
  final Widget child;
  final Widget floatingActButton;

  GerenciadorTelaLogada(
      {@required this.titulo, this.child, this.floatingActButton});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(this.titulo),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      drawer: GMenu(),
      floatingActionButton: this.floatingActButton,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Color(0xff5b71b3),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: this.child ?? const SizedBox(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can reuse that widget with any other class

```
class CBandeira extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _CBandeiraState createState() => _CBandeiraState();
    }


class _CBandeiraState extends State<CBandeira> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

var formInputs = <GTextBox>[];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Now you can use it in other's widget build method and create your own child, title and fab
    return GerenciadorTelaLogada(
       titulo: "Cadastro de Bandeira",
       floatingActButton: FloatingActionButton(
         child: Icon(
           Icons.save,
           color: Colors.white,
         ),
         backgroundColor: Colors.green,
         onPressed: () {
           if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
             Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
               content: Text("Test"),
             ));
           }
         },
       ),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  formInputs[index].icon,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                title: formInputs[index],
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SizedBox(height: 10);
            },
            itemCount: formInputs.length),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I used a Scaffold before creating the widget, thats why I didn't see the error, now I see it and what you have to do in this case is wrap the widget that you want to use `Scaffold.of(context)` with a Builder, it lets you create a new context and after that it can check above in the tree for a scaffold. Before that the're both in the same context, that's why it didn't find it

```
class CBandeira extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _CBandeiraState createState() => _CBandeiraState();
    }


class _CBandeiraState extends State<CBandeira> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

var formInputs = <GTextBox>[
GTextBox(
  label: "Código",
  tipo: TextBoxTipo.numerico,
  icon: Icons.person,
),
GTextBox(
  label: "Nome",
  tipo: TextBoxTipo.tudo,
  icon: Icons.person,
  validator: (valor) {
    if (valor.length < 3) {
      return 'Nome muito curto';
    }
    return null;
  },
),
GTextBox(
  label: "Descrição",
  tipo: TextBoxTipo.tudo,
  icon: Icons.details,
),
];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Now you can use it in other's widget build method and create your own child, title and fab
    return GerenciadorTelaLogada(
       titulo: "Cadastro de Bandeira",
       floatingActButton: Builder( //with this It can now check for a scaffold above the tree
         builder: (context){
           return  FloatingActionButton(
         child: Icon(
           Icons.save,
           color: Colors.white,
         ),
         backgroundColor: Colors.green,
         onPressed: () {
           if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
             Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
               content: Text("Test"),
             ));
           }
         },
       );
         },
       ),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  formInputs[index].icon,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                title: formInputs[index],
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SizedBox(height: 10);
            },
            itemCount: formInputs.length),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE WITH GLOBAL KEY**

```
class GerenciadorTelaLogada extends StatelessWidget {
  final String titulo;
  final Widget child;
  final Widget floatActButton;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;

  const GerenciadorTelaLogada(
      {this.child, @required this.titulo, @required this.scaffoldKey, this.floatActButton});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey, //use it here
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(this.titulo),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),

      floatingActionButton: this.floatActButton,

      // Side Menu
      //drawer: GMenu(),

      // Corpo do DashBoard
      body: SafeArea(
          child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        child: Container(
          child: this.child ?? const SizedBox(),
          color: Color(0xff5b71b3),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Função executada quando clicar no botão de salvar
  final VoidCallback onSalvar;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey;
  final String titulo;
  final Widget child;

  /// Construtor
  const GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro(
      {@required this.titulo, @required this.scaffoldKey, this.child, @required this.onSalvar});

// Costroi a parte excluisa das telas de cadastro
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Retorna a tela base construida com as informações possiveis em uma tela.
    return GerenciadorTelaLogada(
      scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey, //pass it to the scaffold
      titulo: this.titulo,
      child: this.child,
      floatActButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.save,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        onPressed: this.onSalvar,
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Just created this but I don't know how it really looks like
class GTextBox{
  final String label;
  final IconData icon;

  GTextBox({this.label, this.icon});
}

class CBandeira extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CBandeiraState createState() => _CBandeiraState();
}

class _CBandeiraState extends State<CBandeira>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  var formInputs = <GTextBox>[
    GTextBox(
      label: "Código",
      tipo: TextBoxTipo.numerico,
      icon: Icons.person,
    ),
    GTextBox(
      label: "Nome",
      tipo: TextBoxTipo.tudo,
      icon: Icons.person,
      validator: (valor) {
        if (valor.length < 3) {
          return 'Nome muito curto';
        }
        return null;
      },
    ),
    GTextBox(
      label: "Descrição",
      tipo: TextBoxTipo.tudo,
      icon: Icons.details,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro(
      scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey, //pass the GlobalKey to the Scaffold
      onSalvar: () {
        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
          //use the scaffoldKey instead
          scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text("Form is valid"),
          ));
        }
      },
      titulo: "Cadastro de Bandeira",
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  formInputs[index].icon,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                title: formInputs[index],
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SizedBox(height: 10);
            },
            itemCount: formInputs.length),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to follow your code but I still don't know why I can't get it to work. This is my final code after your answer: https://i.imgur.com/uACJ1jO.png
What am I missing? Same Scaffold context error when trying to show the snackbar

Comment: can you post it as a gist or edit your post with this code, it's hard to tell from a picture

Comment: Sure. Here is my gist link: https://gist.github.com/SheenBR

Comment: I run your gist (commenting the drawer and the GtextBox because I don't have those classes) with out problem, what error do you have?

Comment: I updated my answer, I made a mistake when running the code, try again with the new one

Comment: Try to use `GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro` just like I did in my gist. Using your code works fine, but I want to be able to show a message from the Widget that uses GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro in the build method, from the `onSalvar` property

Comment: yeah I see, the problem with that is that the scaffold is at the end (GerenciadorTelaLogada) and the onSave is first in the context, why not try building it like GerenciadorTelaLogada > CBandeira > GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro

Comment: I'm thinking about this way: GerenciadorTela has the base template for the screen. GerenciadorTelaCadastro extends that screen but adds the floatingActionbutton. Then CBandeira uses that GerenciadorTelaCadastro and properly give an action to that button, with the possibility to show messages on screen by itself, aswell as any other classes if I wanted to

Comment: The only solution I have for that is to use a GlobalKey and pass it from CBandeira to GerenciadorTelaLogadaCadastro and then GerenciadorTelaLogada, see my update

Comment: Thanks! I think it works now. Can you explain to me how this logic works? I will mark this as answered already though.

Comment: the methods .of(context) checks for an ancestor in the widget tree, but there is no ancestor of any state of an scaffold because it's build at the same time and with the same context, so a way around is using a GlobalKey that you declare previously and pass it to an state of the object you want to keep on check, that way when you attach the globalKey to the widget you know it exists, because you purposely created it, and that way you can use knowing that it exists, check more of the documentation at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html